# Объединяем массив

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день, имею массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /spektrometry1/
    [1] => спектрометр
)
Array
(
    [0] => /spektrometry/
    [1] => спектрометры
)
Array
(
    [0] => /spektrometry/
    [1] => спектроскопы
)
```

Вопрос как объединить одинаковые массивы с данными, в нашем случае [0] и привязать к нему все значения [1] ?

Comment: Если просто объединить массивы то есть такая штука:  [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) — Сливает один или большее количество массивов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом код будет немного отличаться, в зависимости от желаемого вида результата, который вы не указали. Но суть всегда будет одна - использовать ассоциативный массив, чтобы группировать значения с одинаковыми ключами.

```
$data = [
          ['/spektrometry1/', 'спектрометр'],
          ['/spektrometry/',  'спектрометры'],
          ['/spektrometry/',  'спектроскопы'],
    ];

$tmp = [];
foreach($data as list($k, $t)){
    $tmp[$k][] = $t;
}

foreach($tmp as $k => $v){
    $result[] = [$k, $v];  // либо [$k, implode(', ', $v)] 
}

print_r($result);
```

результат

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /spektrometry1/
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => спектрометр
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => /spektrometry/
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => спектрометры
                [1] => спектроскопы
            )

    )
```

возможно вам хватит и промежуточного результата, который в `$tmp`

Comment: У меня к вам вопрос, можно оставить комментарий к каждому действию? Если я правильно понял, то: $data = [
          ['/spektrometry1/', 'спектрометр'],
          ['/spektrometry/',  'спектрометры'],
          ['/spektrometry/',  'спектроскопы'],
    ]; // Это у нас массив

$tmp = []; // Создаем Пустой массив
foreach($data as list($k, $t)){
    $tmp[$k][] = $t; // В цикле присваиваем ассоциативные переменные и далее в массив $tmp мы приклеиваем в пустой массив $t
}
foreach($tmp as $k => $v){
    $result[] = [$k, $v];  // ВОТ это мне не понятно, как работает?
}
print_r($result);

Comment: @sanitarn `$result[]` или `$tmp[$k][]` это добавление элемента в массив. Т.е. в первом случае это не приклеиваем в пустой, а добавляем к имеющемуся `$tmp[$k]`. Во втором случае с `$result` просто добавляем в массив новый вложенный массив из двух элементов `[$k $v]`.